# mvc jquery post form data and assign form data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I use mvc 4,

I want to post form data in jquery and set json data to form.

```
function DoAjaxPostAndMore(btnClicked) {
var $form = $(btnClicked).parents('form');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    data: $form.serialize(),
    accept: 'application/json',
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {

    },
    success: function (response) {            

    }
});

return false;// if it's a link to prevent post}
```

Comment: Do you have any questions?

Comment: @OP Good, so now what solution you want from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this----

```
$.each(data, function(name, val){
    var $frm = $('[name="'+name+'"]'),
        type = $frm.attr('type');

    switch(type){
        case 'checkbox':
            $frm.attr('checked', 'checked');
            break;
        case 'radio':
            $frm.filter('[value="'+val+'"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
            break;
        default:
            $frm.val(val);
    }
});
```

Check the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/2xdkt/

Answer (score 0):

WHAT IS THAT `parents()` function for ???
TRY this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $('form').attr('action');
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    accept: 'application/json',
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {

    },
    success: function (response) {            

    }
});
```

Comment: ok sorry my code is true no problem but I want to set form data from json, response type json and same my model data. I can this $("#FormEntity_Id").val(response.FormEntity.Id); but I dont want use this code because I have a lot of forms, thanks for helps